# Need help with combinatorics question(probably cyclical permutation)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A human invites 6 of his friends to a meeting. In how many different arrangements they along with the human's wife can sit at a round table if the hosts and the wife always sit together?

Is this a cyclical permutation problem? Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably intended that any rotation of the people is considered to produce the"same" arrangement, meaning that yes, this is intended to be a cyclic permutation problem.

That is not the only possible interpretation, since the host might like to be nearest to the kitchen. And the views from the chairs are different.

To solve, since we can rotate the people without changing the arrangement, let one of the chairs be a throne, and let the host's spouse sit there. Then the host can be placed in $2$ ways. And for each of these ways, the $6$ guests $\dots$.

Comment: So, basically this question is ambiguous. 
If it is normal permutations then the answer is $6!.2$.

Comment: There is some ambiguity. But I am reasonably sure that the "correct" answer is $(2)(6!)$. In all too many cases, introductory combinatorics questions are worded carelessly. The problem comes from the desire to use "real-world" wording. Round table here is code for use cyclic permutations.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.
Cyclical permutation has the following concept:
Suppose we have $n$ objects then to determine the cyclical permutations we can fix one of the objects at a point, and the rest can be arranged in $(n-1)!$.
Similarly, we can arrange the guy and his wife among themselves in $2!$ and the rest can be arranged in $6!$ and by the rule of product, no. of different arrangements is $6!.2$

Comment: Yes, that is another way of getting the same thing. I got the same thing by imagining the spouse at a specific place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you place wife and husband at the table (you can do this in $8\cdot 2$ ways, since you can place a pair at any place and for each choice you can switch wife and husband). Then you place left guests in $6!$ ways. So there are $8\cdot2\cdot6!$ arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

You have 8 people. We know that the host and his wife must sit together. So we sit the host first: we have 8 choices, and, for each choice, we can sit his wife either on his right or his left; thus we have $8\times2$ ways. Now, once you have fixed the position of the host and his wife, you can sit the 6 guests as you like, i.e. in $6!$ ways. So in total we have $2\times8\times6!=11520$ arrangements.

Comment: My textbook disagrees.
It says 1440. :(

Comment: I can see why the book says 1440. However, the book should specify that we consider two configurations the same if we can get from one to another via a rotation of the table. For me, it is more natural to think that it is possible to tell the difference between these equivalent permutations (e.g. the host is facing South, or is near the entrance door, or whatever the points of reference are).

Comment: I agree with you, and that would be why I posted the question here.